# Date parse format from T with time to mm/dd/yyyy with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the following value:

**javascript variable:**

```
"2015-10-14T17:54:19.033"
```

I want to end up with

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

e.g.

```
10/14/2015
```

I was trying to do

```
var date = month[d.getMonth()]  + " " + d.getDay()+ ", " + d.getFullYear();
```

**Here is my Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/7ptcedt4/

```
var d = new Date('2015-10-14T17:54:19.033');

var date = d.getMonth().toString() + "/" + d.getDay().toString() + "/" +    d.getFullYear().toString();

console.log(date);
```

**Something is NOT right:  I am getting**

```
 9/3/2015
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. What was the issue?

Comment: Adding a Fiddle, the month and day are not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var date = new Date("2015-10-14T17:54:19.033");
var formatedDateString = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
```

Or use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var formatedDateString = moment("2015-10-14T17:54:19.033").format('MM/dd/YYYY');
```

Or may you consider create your own date format function.

PS.: javascript months are 0-indexed, so for the correct month you should use `(date.getMonth() + 1)`